# How do I stop/pause/disable an animated gif on react native?

Tags: react-native

React native added support for animated GIFs in [this ticket](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24).  This is great.  However, there are times when I do not actually want to animate the gif.

If there a way to turn off the gif animations in a React Native Image view?

Answer (score 0):

I have a rather expensive solution for this. But hear me out anyway.
You can create thumbnails for the gif. And change state after tapping. Does that help?